# php: Get SRV record for a specific port with dns_get_record

Tags: php, minecraft, srv-record

I configured this SRV records for my domain for my minecraft server (port 225565)

[image]
This works for minecraft itself. The new server url is mc.marc.tv:

[image]

BUT my monitor script in php does not find the SRV record:

```php
<?php
$record = dns_get_record('_minecraft._tcp.mc.marc.tv');
var_dump($record);
?>
```

This is empty. But dig on my shell

```shell
dig SRV _minecraft._tcp.mc.marc.tv
```

returns this:

```html
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> SRV _minecraft._tcp.mc.marc.tv
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 15689
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;_minecraft._tcp.mc.marc.tv.    IN    SRV

;; ANSWER SECTION:
_minecraft._tcp.mc.marc.tv. 1455 IN    SRV    0 5 25565 u5xvqz2hcvrlrpgm.myfritz.net.

;; Query time: 5 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.178.1#53(192.168.178.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Mar 28 22:41:08 CET 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 103
```

What did I do wrong? How do I get the SRV record for this subdomain with php for a specific port only? Or did i configure the server wrong?

Comment: Weird, it works for me.

Comment: Ok, what happens if you execute the php part? All I get is


array (size=0)
  empty


for $record = dns_get_record('_minecraft._tcp.mc.marc.tv');
var_dump($record);

Comment: On my side I get : array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(8) {
    ["host"]=>
    string(26) "_minecraft._tcp.mc.marc.tv"
    ["class"]=>
    string(2) "IN"
    ["ttl"]=>
    int(5559)
    ["type"]=>
    string(3) "SRV"
    ["pri"]=>
    int(0)
    ["weight"]=>
    int(5)
    ["port"]=>
    int(25565)
    ["target"]=>
    string(28) "u5xvqz2hcvrlrpgm.myfritz.net"
  }
}.

I would advise you to refresh your DNS cache maybe ?

Comment: ok... thats weird. I tested it at home, with my cellphone... Thanks. Now I know where I have to look. =)

Answer (score 1):

I just had to wait because the DNS of the php server was not updated yet. So patience was the key.